# move focus between sub-windows (or buffers?) with ctrl-tab?

Tags: buffers, focus

Currently using GNU Emacs 23.1.1.

I've used xemacs since the late 90s and am only now switching to proper emacs.

If I had my xemacs window split into a top buffer and bottom buffer, I could move the keyboard focus between them with ctrl-tab.  *(I cannot remember if that's something I wrote myself 20+ years ago, or was a standard mapping, but checking my config files I don't think I wrote it myself.)*

There are similar questions about rotating *between* buffers, but, I think, keeping the focus in the same sub-window.  That's not my question, but just to be clear, the following is something I find very useful but isn't what this current question is asking.  I probably have the wrong terminology, but the following code changes the buffer within the current sub-window.  Instead I want to leave all the sub-windows looking at their current buffers, and instead move focus to the next sub-wind.

> (defun switch-to-next-buffer ()   (interactive)   (switch-to-buffer
>   (other-buffer)))

Comment: Are you looking for `other-window` bound to `C-x o`?

Comment: Yes Tobias, that seems to be it.  If you could provide that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.  BTW is there another command I could bind to ctrl-shift-tab to go backwards, should I have many windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnu Emacs has the function [`other-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Window.html) which is bound to <kbd>C-x o</kbd>.

The relevant section from the doc string of `other-window`:

> `(other-window COUNT &optional ALL-FRAMES)`
>   ...
>   Select another window in cyclic ordering of windows.
>   COUNT specifies the number of windows to skip, starting with the
>   selected window, before making the selection.  If COUNT is
>   positive, skip COUNT windows forwards.  If COUNT is negative,
>   skip -COUNT windows backwards.  COUNT zero means do not skip any
>   window, so select the selected window.  In an interactive call,
>   COUNT is the numeric prefix argument.

So the keysequence <kbd>C-<minus></kbd> <kbd>C-x o</kbd> gives you the inverse of <kbd>C-x o</kbd>. Note that <kbd>C-<minus></kbd> stands for the numeric prefix arg `-1`.

Comment: that anticipated my next question--how to go backwards--as well; thanks!